# Open URL with Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, browser

I noticed that if I type a URL into Windows Explorer, it will open the URL in
default browser. I tried this on command line as well:

```
explorer.exe https://superuser.com
```

but I noticed that the command line version launches a new `explorer.exe`
process. When using Windows Explorer GUI, the action is performed with the
original `explorer.exe` process.

Is it possible to open URL from command line with `explorer.exe` using the
existing process? I would prefer this as it seems the additional `explorer.exe`
processes remain even after closing the browser.

Comment: Do you need to use explorer.exe, if you need to for some reason please explain why, because there are commands that let you open webpages in cmd other than explorer.exe

Comment: Did you ever get answer? I need this to make sharepoint shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

Here some workaround for URLs:

```
rundll32 url,OpenURL https://superuser.com
rundll32 url,FileProtocolHandler https://superuser.com
```

and for local files:

```
rundll32 url,OpenURL C:\superuser.txt
rundll32 url,FileProtocolHandler C:\superuser.txt
rundll32 shell32,ShellExec_RunDLL C:\superuser.txt
```

https://github.com/LOLBAS-Project/LOLBAS/blob/master/Archive-Old-Version/OSLibraries/Url.dll.md

Answer (score 1):

Like rtyocum said,

you can put this in a .bat file (batch).

**Start iexplore www.google.com**

Don't use quotation marks.

You could also create a new shortcut and paste the folowing in the target path :

**"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" www.google.com**

Then give the shortcut a proper name e.g. google

You could also implement this in the registry under :

**HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell**

Win XP doesn't have this key but there are workarounds for that.

If you need explanation on how to create the registry key, ask.

Answer (score 1):

To open with your default browser, just use:

```
start https://superuser.com/questions/1456314/open-url-with-windows-explorer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `”Start iexplore www.google.com”`
Or use the process of your browser such as chrome or firefox. You may have to point it directly to the browser executable